# Python subprocess stdout truncated by env variable $COLUMNS

Tags: python, bash, subprocess

I am calling a bash script in python (3.4.3) using subprocess:

```
import subprocess as sp
res = sp.check_output("myscript", shell=True)
```

and **myscript** contains a line:

```
ps -ef | egrep somecommand
```

It was not giving the same result as when **myscript** is directly called in a bash shell window. After much tinkering, I realized that when **myscript** is called in python, the stdout of "ps -ef" was truncated by the current $COLUMNS value of the shell window before being piped to "egrep". To me, this is crazy as simply by resizing the shell window, the command can give different results!

I managed to "solve" the problem by passing **env** argument to the subprocess call to specify a wide enough COLUMNS:

```
res = sp.check_output("myscript", shell=True, env={'COLUMNS':'100'})
```

However, this looks very dirty to me and I don't understand why the truncation only happens in python subprocess but not in a bash shell. Frankly I'm amazed that this behavior isn't documented in the official python doc unless it's in fact a bug -- I am using python 3.4.3. What is the proper way of avoiding this strange behavior?

Comment: unrelated: to preserve other environment variables you could use `env=dict(os.environ, COLUMNS='100')` instead of `env={'COLUMNS':'100'}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shoud use `-ww`, from `man ps`:

> -w
>
> Wide output. Use this option twice for unlimited width.

Comment: Thanks, so it was actually ps that is truncating its output based on current $COLUMNS -- why does it not truncate when called directly in the bash shell window?

Comment: It happens in bash too, try: `COLUMNS=8 ps -ef` and you'll see truncated output

Comment: `COLUMNS` is not normally exported, it is set by the shell.  In interactive mode it will be set to the correct size.  See option `setwinsize` in `man bash`.

Comment: Not sure I understood - in my bash shell, I can see $COLUMNS being updated automatically as I resize the window. But it seems that this value is not "seen" by a `ps -ef` entered in the bash shell, whereas explicitly adding COLUMNS=8 as Diego suggests does affect the ps.